# Brightway2: LCA scores & calculations

Tags: python, brightway

My problem is about getting emissions results of my functional unit from a ecoinvent excel spreadsheet format.
I managed to get activities/process impacts thanks to `ca.annotated_top_processes(lca)` or `lca.top_activities()`but emissions/biosphere flows can't be displayed but through `ca.hinton_matrix(lca, rows=10, cols=10)`. How can I get specific scores ?
Here's the situation:

```
import brightway2 as bw
from stats_arrays import *
import bw2analyzer as bwa
projects.set_current("excel_import_verif1")
bw.databases
db = bw.Database('IoTBOLLCA') #Excel spreadsheet
CC = [method for method in bw.methods if "('ReCiPe Midpoint (H) V1.13', 'climate change', 'GWP100')" in str(method)][0]
FU = [i for i in db if 'FU' in i['name']][0]
lca = bw.LCA({FU:1},CC)
lca.lci()
lca.lcia()
lca.score
ca = bwa.ContributionAnalysis()
lca.top_emissions()
```

and I get this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\Anaconda3\envs\bw2\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_sputils.py:208, in isintlike(x)
    207 try:
--> 208     operator.index(x)
    209 except (TypeError, ValueError):

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [28], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 lca.top_emissions()

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\bw2\lib\site-packages\bw2calc\lca.py:575, in LCA.top_emissions(self, **kwargs)
    573 except ImportError:
    574     raise ImportError("`bw2analyzer` is not installed")
--> 575 return ContributionAnalysis().annotated_top_emissions(self, **kwargs)

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\bw2\lib\site-packages\bw2analyzer\contribution.py:152, in ContributionAnalysis.annotated_top_emissions(self, lca, names, **kwargs)
    146 """Get list of most damaging biosphere flows in an LCA, sorted by ``abs(direct impact)``.
    147 
    148 Returns a list of tuples: ``(lca score, inventory amount, activity)``. If ``names`` is False, they returns the process key as the last element.
    149 
    150 """
    151 ra, rp, rb = lca.reverse_dict()
--> 152 results = [
    153     (score, lca.inventory[index, :].sum(), rb[index])
    154     for score, index in self.top_emissions(
    155         lca.characterized_inventory, **kwargs
    156     )
    157 ]
    158 if names:
    159     results = [(x[0], x[1], get_activity(x[2])) for x in results]

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\bw2\lib\site-packages\bw2analyzer\contribution.py:153, in <listcomp>(.0)
    146 """Get list of most damaging biosphere flows in an LCA, sorted by ``abs(direct impact)``.
    147 
    148 Returns a list of tuples: ``(lca score, inventory amount, activity)``. If ``names`` is False, they returns the process key as the last element.
    149 
    150 """
    151 ra, rp, rb = lca.reverse_dict()
    152 results = [
--> 153     (score, lca.inventory[index, :].sum(), rb[index])
    154     for score, index in self.top_emissions(
    155         lca.characterized_inventory, **kwargs
    156     )
    157 ]
    158 if names:
    159     results = [(x[0], x[1], get_activity(x[2])) for x in results]

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\bw2\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_index.py:47, in IndexMixin.__getitem__(self, key)
     46 def __getitem__(self, key):
---> 47     row, col = self._validate_indices(key)
     49     # Dispatch to specialized methods.
     50     if isinstance(row, INT_TYPES):

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\bw2\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_index.py:152, in IndexMixin._validate_indices(self, key)
    149 M, N = self.shape
    150 row, col = _unpack_index(key)
--> 152 if isintlike(row):
    153     row = int(row)
    154     if row < -M or row >= M:

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\bw2\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_sputils.py:216, in isintlike(x)
    214     if loose_int:
    215         msg = "Inexact indices into sparse matrices are not allowed"
--> 216         raise ValueError(msg)
    217     return loose_int
    218 return True

ValueError: Inexact indices into sparse matrices are not allowed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error [as of Scipy version 1.9](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/release.1.9.0.html#expired-deprecations); for now, you can force a downgrade to Scipy 1.8.something.

This has [been noted as an issue](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-analyzer/issues/20), but the focus for BW development is in other areas currently.